# What is the modularization story for TypeScript in the browser?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, typescript1.4

I am new to browser development, so I have no prior experience with AMD, CommonJS, UMD, Browserify, RequireJS, etc.  I have been reading a lot about them and I believe I *generally* understand the JavaScript story but I am still very confused as to how to make everything work together.

I have a library written in TypeScript.  It is a pure TypeScript library, it doesn't interact with a browser or any browser framework nor any node or NPM things.

I also have a TypeScript client application that leverages this library.  The client application may leverages a web framework as well (e.g., jQuery).

Now when I compile my two TypeScript files (which we will assume are in separate projects, isolated from each other and built separately), each will generate a .js file.  In Visual Studio I have to choose AMD or Common as my module loader.

This is where things fall apart.  My research tells me that if I want to work on the web I either need to use Browserify or RequireJS.  Browserify appears to require I first install Node on my machine and then use a command line tool as a post-build step to generate a file and as far as I can tell this isn't available as a NuGet package.  Alternatively, I can use RequireJS but then all of the examples stop working.  Something about not doing things on window load and instead doing them somewhere else, but nothing that I have found really explains that well.

So, what is the story here?  I want to use TypeScript but at the moment it really feels like it is just a language, there aren't any compelling usage stories available to me as a developer as I have grown accustomed to in the Microsoft ecosystem.

Comment: Covered here as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript does support AMD and CommonJS just as JavaScript. But *in addition* it also supports [internal modules](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript). When using internal modules in conjunction with a decent build system like [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) you'll find that internal modules can cover lot of use cases where one would choose AMD/CommonJS in traditional JavaScript projects.

TypeScript gives you the freedom to decide yourself. If you need asynchronous module loading you are free to use AMD via external modules. You can also use CommonJS and/or use [browserify](http://browserify.org) to link together your code into a single file.

I've found that when you are a library developer - that is you ship your TypeScript compiled JS code to other developers - internal modules are a good compromise. You don't force your target audience (developers) to use any special module system like AMD/CommonJS, but instead ship isomorphic JS that runs in the browser as well as in node. Yet you still have a way of modularizing your code internally, just as AMD/CommonJS would allow you.

TL;DR: When you use TypeScript you get internal modules for free, and they provide you with a flexibility that would else only be achieved by AMD/CommonJS. Yet external modules still have their advantages. In the end, you should decide what is the best fit for your project.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so its story is the story of JS, not of .NET or any other Microsoft product.

If you compile your TypeScript modules to AMD, then you load them through an AMD module loader like RequireJS (or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org), or [curl](https://github.com/cujojs/curl)) in your entrypoint HTML file, which can be as simple as this (using RequireJS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Application name</title>
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/client"></script>
```

(Assuming that your built TypeScript module is `scripts/client.js`.)

The [Start page for RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) or the [Dojo Introduction to AMD modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) are both resources that can tell you more about how to load AMD-formatted modules in a browser.

Comment: If I follow those steps, my window.onload event isn't hit.  This event is hooked up by the TypeScript sample app and many online examples hook up this event.  I believe this is because window.onload fires before RequireJS has loaded my module.  Googling suggests that I need to require domReady (third party script).  Unfortunately, I am back to lost now because I don't know how to tell TypeScript to require a non-TypeScript dependency.  I tried import `domReady = require("Scripts/domReady")` after downloading it but that didn't work.

Comment: If the `<script>` tag is placed at the end of the page (immediately before `</body>`) you do not need to wait for anything, since all the content has been loaded by then. You only need to wait for the load event if you need all data including external resources like images to load, and you only need to listen for content ready if you aren’t putting your script at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You got a really good technical answer from C Snover, but the answer you're actually looking for is "don't use external modules".  By external modules, I mean "AMD" or "CommonJS" modules.

If you actually need what external modules offer, they can be very useful, but they come at a *significant* cost in terms of build/deployment complexity and concepts that you need to understand.

Just because external modules are way more complicated doesn't mean they're better; the TypeScript compiler itself is written using internal modules.

You can convert an external module back to an internal module by omitting any export statements on the module itself (and by not having an `export =` statement at the end of the file either).  For example, this is an internal module:

```
module MyLibrary {
  export class MyClass {
    public Foo = 1;    
  }
}
```

If you are using internal modules, all you have to do is reference them in the right order via script tags in your HTML files and they will work without having to deal with any sort of loader system.

```
<script src="MyLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="MyUICode.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your opinion that "don't use external modules" is useful recommendation is not very useful both from maintainability perspective and mainly from the [PageSpeed - Make the Web Faster - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) perspective. Among the rules of thumb is minimize client server traffic by bundling multiple scripts together and minify resources. What you recommend goes clearly against the best practice

Comment: I'd say that when using TypeScript, you should think twice if you really need AMD/CommonJS modules. The TypeScript compiler provides a really good way of modularizing your code using the internal modules. With internal modules, you get a single file JavaScript file that can be minified and will load very quickly. To achieve this with AMD/requireJS you'd ultimately have to pull in r.js that compiles to a single .js file - just as TypeScript does. I am not saying TypeScript renders AMD/CommonJS obsolete, but you should have good reasons to choose them over internal modules.

Comment: @xmojmr Respectfully, the question was about modularization of TypeScript code for consumption in the browser, not about minification or bundling.  My answer was correct based on the question asked, though Dyna offered a better description as to why.  Regarding "clearly against best practices", two internal modules bundled and minified to a single JS file will result in fewer bytes requested and one fewer HTTP request when compared to a module loader library *plus* the same bundled/minified JS.

Comment: @NYCdotNet **IF** the core of OP's question is in "_I am new to browser development...my two TypeScript files...stop working_" then the question as such should be closed as ["why isn't this code working...off-topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but your answer would be perfectly correct and useful. **IF** the core of OP's question is in "_I am new to browser development...What is the modularization story..._" then your answer is misguiding as there's a good reason why some respected authors [recommend (external) modularization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/260462/129832)